# Como alterar o texto de acordo com a imagem mostrada no slide?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Olá. Sou iniciante em web development. Segue minha dúvida:

Embora tenha conseguido alterar as imagens, não consigo fazer com que juntamente com cada imagem o conteúdo dentro dela seja igualmente alterado de acordo com o slide.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado!

```
<div class="slider-sec">
<div class="slider single-item">
<!--<div><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Slogan" /></div>-->
<div><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Slogan"/></div>
<div><img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="Slogan"/></div>
<div><img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt="Slogan"/></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns no-pad">
<div class="banner-txt"><h1 class="alternate">Conheça a XX XX</h1>
<a href="#" class="button round">Descubra como</a>
</div></div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.single-item').slick();
</script>     
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.single-item').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
    });
```

Comment: *"o conteúdo dentro dela"* que conteúdo exatamente? explique melhor

Comment: O conteúdo que está inserido na imagem slide1.jpg é o que está definido na                                         <div class="banner-txt"><h1 class="alternate>Conheça a XX XX</h1><a href="#" class="button round">Descubra como</a></div></div>                                               Ele aparece na primeira imagem (slide1.jpg), mas continua aparecendo nas outras imagens inalterado, que é o que eu gostaria de mudar, basicamente criar uma mensagem para cada mudança (slick) de imagem.                                          Obrigado, desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acredito que você deve colocar o conteúdo dentro de cada `<div>`

```
<div class="slider-sec">
    <div class="slider single-item">  
        <div><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Slogan" /> Seu conteúdo aqui </div>
        <div><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Slogan"/> Seu conteúdo aqui </div>
        <div><img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="Slogan"/> Seu conteúdo aqui </div>
        <div><img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt="Slogan"/> Seu conteúdo aqui </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exatamente. Para resolver, eu inseri  a  <div class="banner-txt"><h1 class="alternate">Conheça a XX XX</h1><a href="#" class="button round">Descubra como</a></div> <!--dentro de cada div onde defini as imagens--> <div><img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt="Slogan"/>.                                                                              Obrigado pela sua ajuda. Foi uma boa primeira experiência utilizando o stack over flow!